How to get the rounded corners back after maximizing the window?
I'm using WindowStyle None and my navbar is a rectangle with RadiusX and RadiusY set to 16 for the Normal WindowState and I want them to be 0 when the window is maximized.
I did manage to get them to 0 when I maximize, but when going to normal afterwards, they don't change back.
Here's what I tried:

Maximized to Normal

            if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
                
            {
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                NavBar.RadiusX = 16;
                NavBar.RadiusY = 16;
            }

            else
                WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                NavBar.RadiusX = 0;
                NavBar.RadiusY = 0;


Normal to Maximized (corners stay round)

            if (WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
                
            {
                WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                NavBar.RadiusX = 0;
                NavBar.RadiusY = 0;
            }

            else
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                NavBar.RadiusX = 16;
                NavBar.RadiusY = 16;

Also copying the navbar rectangle, changing the radii and setting it to hidden in the XAML and trying to toggle the visibility in C#, like this:
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
                
            {
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                NavBarM.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }

            else
                WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                NavBarM.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

That got me the same result as the first one.

Is this your actual code? It looks like you are missing some { } in the else parts.

Oh wow that actually fixed it. It is my code, Visual Studio doesn't seem to mind if miss the curly brackets in the "else" section but it trips out if I don't include them in the "if" section.

The braces are not required for single line blocks. But whenever you have more than one statement, you need braces. Some might even suggest using  braces always, no matter how many lines.

As 001 pointed out, it is obvious that the second and third lines after else without braces are out of scope of that else. Thus those lines will be always executed.

Can we close this issue? You already received correct comments helping you to deal with your if blocks. And I'll add something completely different: the interest here is not to touch any code-behind, View Model, and no code at all. After all, what you want are mere decorative details. It would be not nice to contaminate code with them.
Let's try to implement it in pure XAML:
    <Window x:Class="SA.Demo.View.WindowMain"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WindowMain" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"
                Padding="10 4 10 4">
            <TextBlock>Place for Navigation Bar</TextBlock>
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger
                            Binding="{Binding WindowState,
                            RelativeSource=
                            {RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                            Value="Maximized">
                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 4"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState,
                            RelativeSource=
                            {RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                            Value="Normal">
                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="9"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8 4 8 4"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Here, RelativeSource binding is used to handle property changed events from the parent Window recognized by its type. I also added another Setter to both data triggers to change the navigation bar border margins, to make it look nicer when the corners get rounded.
I hope you don't want to change also the navigation bar visibility any longer, but if you want, you don't need any setters in the data triggers except
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
<!-- ... -->
<!-- and -->
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>

This way, you could change the navigation bar visibility depending on the window state, so border radius and other properties could be static because you don't need to change them if the element is invisible.
